# State not 'resetting' when going 'back' to page from 'child' route

Tags: reactjs

I have a route that has 'child' routes. When I go to a child route and then go `back` via the browser state doesn't reset. If I visit a non-child route and then go `back` to that route state resets as normal.

I've tried hackey methods of resetting state manually when leaving the page but these haven't worked.

```
function App() {
 <Route path='/stories' render={() => <Stories />} />
}

class Stories extends Component {

 render() {
   return (
     <React.Fragment>
       <Route exact path="/stories" render={() =>
         <div>
           ...
         </div>
       } />
       <Route path={`/stories/first-story`} render={_=> <Story />} />
       <Route path={`/stories/second-story`} render={_=> <Story /> />
     </React.Frament>
 )
}
```

I want state to reset when I go back to the `stories` page from a child route.

Answer (score 1):

The state doesn't reset because you are still within the same react component tree. The parent element hasn't unmounted and remounted, it's simply re-rendered.

Example:

1. You go to your site example.com. The App component is rendered.
2. You click on a link that leads you to example.com/stories. The App component now renders it's child element Stories.
3. From example.com/stories, you hit Back in the browser and are taken again to example.com. App has now ceased to render the Stories element (as the route no longer matches)
4. You browse to example.com/users. Route is loaded from a different page served by the server.
5. You hit Back in the browser to go back to example.com. All changes that were made to state are now gone.

If you want to reset the state on the browser 'back' function, you'll need to create a listener for 'back' and reset the state or possibly a componentDidMount that inspects the router history to see where it came from and then if it matches conditions, reset state.